# How to make a fitted curve and evaluate an array along that curve

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I am attempting to convert my advisor's Matlab code into Python and having trouble getting past this point in the code.  He uses a CSV of temperature and alpha values (50 each), creates a fitted curve based on their relationship, and evaluates a new set of temperature values (5000) for their corresponding alpha values along that curve.

The scipy.optimize.curve_fit() function has come up a lot in my search, but the final line come in the form of:

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)
```

when all that I want is one single array returned. The code I am working with looks like:

```
def alpha_fit(temp):
    # temp is the 5000-value long temperature that I want to be evaluated
    csv = pd.read_csv('temp_alpha_file.csv',header=None,names=['temp','alpha'])
    temp0 = csv['temp']
    alpha0 = csv['alpha']
    
    # what I am hoping to create:
    make_alpha = magic_curve_fit(temp0,alpha0)
    # where magic_curve_fit creates a function (make_alpha) that will evaluate an array along the curve of temp0, alpha0

    alpha = make_alpha(temp)
    return alpha
```

Does something like this exist? I'm sure it has to.  I'm just having a heck of a time searching for assistance on the internet though I am probably not using the correct search terms.

Comment: In order to do a fit, you first need to define a model function to which to fit the data (e.g. a linear function, a parabola, etc.).

Comment: Did you read https://machinelearningmastery.com/curve-fitting-with-python/ or https://scipy-lectures.org/intro/scipy/auto_examples/plot_curve_fit.html? That's what I found when searching for "scipy curve fit tutorial".

Comment: "In order to do a fit, you first need to define a model function to which to fit the data (e.g. a linear function, a parabola, etc.)."

Could you expand on this a little @mkrieger1 ? Sorry - I'm not a very good programmer.  I am reading into the two links you posted as well.  

Really appreciate it!